# Substitution for fresh corn

Tags: substitutions

I have a recipe for sweet corn bread and it calls for fresh corn and it is very hard to find fresh corn in winter; can it be replaced with frozen corn?

Comment: Hello Irene and welcome! Please see the answer to this question, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46288/when-using-fresh-corn-in-place-of-canned-or-frozed-should-i-cook-the-corn-first/46289#46289.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find frozen or canned is usually much better quality taste and texture wise to the fresh cobs. Good quality canned/frozen sweet corn is picked and frozen/canned within hours of picking whereas cobs in the market could easily be over a week old by the time you get it home.

So yes, you can easily substitute canned/frozen for fresh.

Same goes for peas.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like fresh, in season, corn.  However, it freezes well and frozen corn is an acceptable substitute.  You could also try canned corn, which would provide a corn punch, but may contain extra salt and/or sugar.